# Messaging Menu Keyboard Shortcut

Tags: 11.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, messaging-menu

In previous versions of Ubuntu, <kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> would open the messaging menu.  In 11.04, the <kbd>Super</kbd> key is captured by the launcher.  I have yet to find a way to quickly open the messaging menu from the keyboard.

Comment: Have you tried to configure another shortcut in the preferences?

Comment: F10 plus an unpredictable number of left or right arrow keys is a bit too much.  I liked the days of before where I would queue up messages and just tap super+m to pop open the menu, see what was waiting and if nothing was important, tap it again to make the menu go away.

I looked through the shortcut prefs a bit but didn't see anything obvious.  Maybe I need to do more digging there.

Answer (score 3):

As DoR said in the a comment, you can hit <kbd>F10</kbd> , then hit the arrow keys to select the Messaging Menu.

Answer (score -1):

Many good shortcuts are gone because Unity. Suggest to remap key in CCSM from "Meta" (or Super) to something else. Did that because of Gnome Do and some Compiz shortcuts